# How to return table data as a variable in a predefined string - SQL

Tags: mysql, url, dynamic, concatenation

I'm looking to generate a list of URLs using table data from our DB. For instance, if I'm querying the ORDERS table I'd like to return that information in URL form.

e.g. the predefined string would be "mysite.com/profile/orders/" and the query would input the ORDER_ID to return the final result of mysite.com/profile/orders/ORDER_ID

I hope that makes sense..any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concatenation:

```
SELECT CONCAT('https://example.com/profile/orders/', order_id) AS order_url
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ...
```

Comment: That most certainly did the trick. Thank you!! I'm still kind of new to the SQL game if that wasn't obvious enough..